# get linear indexing for filtered sublist items

Tags: python, list, filter, list-comprehension

rather specific question that is hard to google/search.  Suppose I have a list of lists:

```
lists = [[30,34,0,0],[455,0,0],[0,509,0,0,0,0,444]]
```

how can I return a list of lists with the following sequential operations:

- remove zero entries
- linearly index remaining entries

expected output:

```
[[0,1],[2],[3,4]]
```

The first part is easy enough to obtain with a list comprehension:

```
lists_no_zeros =  [[value for value in row if value != 0] for row in lists]
```

Surely some combination of list comprehensions, zip, enumerate should do the trick..

Comment: Please edit code you have tried into your question. You seem to have some ideas of the python functions you might use - show us what you have tried beyond that one-liner

Comment: It is impossible to return the same list with a list comprehension, this creates a new list

Comment: @Chris_Rands edited for your viewing pleasure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are half way there. You can use `itertools.count()` to get the indexes:

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> c = count()
>>> lists = [[30,34,0,0],[455,0,0],[0,509,0,0,0,0,444]]
>>> [[next(c) for value in sublist if value] for sublist in lists]
[[0, 1], [2], [3, 4]]
```